# Import Excel file using skiprows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

What's the best way to import an excel file? I want ignore all the rows until the date row, 8. Whatever combination of skiprows or headers, I can't get row 8 as the header.

```
df = pd.read_excel('sheet.xlsm', skiprows=8, header =1)
df.head(10)
0 col1  col2   Unnamed: 2        Unnamed: 3
1 NaN   comm    comm1            com2
...
8 NaN   NaN     2010-01-01     2010-02-02
```

I then tried the below, which sort of worked (I ignore the data values for simplicity):

```
df.columns = df.iloc[8].values
  NaN    NaN  2010-01-01     2010-02-02
0
1
```

But when I try to rename the first two columns that are called NaN, I can't:

```
df.rename(columns={df.columns[0] :"col1", df.columns[1]: "col2"})
  
   col2    col2      2010-01-01     2010-02-02
0
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by:-

Firstly:-

```
df=pd.read_excel('sheet.xlsm')
```

Now extract the columns value:-

```
col=df.columns
```

Now finally:-

```
df = pd.read_excel('sheet.xlsm', skiprows=8)
df.columns=col
```

Comment: This doesn't work.How do I read the excel file directly using skiprows?